# I have limited IP space in my AWS VPC. How do I setup Kubernetes in AWS where worker nodes and control plane are in different subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have limited IP's in my public facing VPC which basically means I cannot run the K8S worker nodes in that VPC since I would not have sufficient IP's to support all the pods. My requirement is to run the control plane in my public facing VPC and the worker nodes in a different VPC with a private IP range (192.168.X.X).

We use traefik for ingress and have deployed traefik as a DaemonSet. These pods are exposed using a Kubernetes service of type NLB. And we created a VPC endpoint on top of this NLB which allows us to access this traefik endpoint through our public facing VPC.

However, based on [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#network-load-balancer-support-on-aws-alpha) it looks like NLB support is still in alpha stage. I am curious what are my other options given the above constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in Kubernetes cluster Pods are running in separate *overlay subnet* that should not overlap with existing IP subnets in VPC.
This functionality is provided by Kubernetes [cluster networking solutions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) like Calico, Flannel, Weave, [etc](https://chrislovecnm.com/kubernetes/cni/choosing-a-cni-provider/).
So, you only need to have enough IP address space to support all cluster nodes.

The main benefit of [using NLB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-support-in-kubernetes-1-9/) is to expose client IP address to pods, so if there are no such requirements, regular ELB would be good for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add secondary CIDR to your vpc and use one of the two options mentioned here to have pods use the secondary vpc CIDR.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/optimize-ip-addresses-usage-by-pods-in-your-amazon-eks-cluster/